# What's the SQL Equivalent of the SPSS Partial Outer Join?

Tags: sql, oracle, spss

I'm working on a project to convert an old SPSS system to Oracle. The current code makes heavy use of partial outer joins, and I'm not sure what the best way to replicate that in SQL would be.

Here's an example of a typical query:

```
SELECT
    TA.A
    TB.B
    TC.C
FROM
    TABLE_A TA
    TABLE_B TB
    TABLE_C TC
PARTIAL OUTER JOIN
    TA.FIELD = TB.FIELD
    AND TB.FIELD = TC.FIELD
```

From what I've read in the [IBM Knowledge Base](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_15.0.0/com.ibm.spss.modeler.help/joins_types.htm), a partial outer join is essentially a left/right outer join that merges multiple tables. IBM provides the following Venn diagram:

[image]

It seems like the best way to replicate this would be to do a full outer join between tables A and C, and then left outer joins from A to C and B to C.

Is that correct? Is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The Venn diagram really doesn't convey what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I asked around the office and one of the senior devs pointed me to [this manual](http://www.medhost.com/secureddocs/hms-sequel-training-manual-june-15-2013.pdf) which defines a partial outer join as

> Returns all records from the primary  file (first file 
>   in the FROM clause) whether or not there is a match in the secondary file(s)

In other words, take the first table in the FROM clause and do a left outer join to all the other tables.

So the original query:

```
 SELECT
      TA.A
      TB.B
      TC.C
 FROM
     TABLE_A TA
     TABLE_B TB
     TABLE_C TC
 PARTIAL OUTER JOIN
     TA.FIELD = TB.FIELD
     AND TB.FIELD = TC.FIELD
```

Should become this:

```
   SELECT
        TA.A
        TB.B
        TC.C
   FROM
      TABLE_A TA LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B TB ON TA.FIELD = TB.FIELD
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C TC ON TA.FIELD = TC.FIELD
```

Comment: That does not align with your Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL using:

```
SELECT
    TA.A,
    TB.B,
    TC.B
FROM
    TABLE_A TA
FULL OUTER JOIN
    TABLE_B TB
    ON  (TA.FIELD = TB.FIELD)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    TABLE_C TC
    ON  (TA.FIELD = TC.FIELD)
    OR  (TB.FIELD = TC.FIELD);
```

Every record in tables A and B will return, even if they do not match. Then only records from table C that match one in A or B will return.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not at all clear.  I'm not sure what SPSS does when there are rows in A and B that match *different* rows in C.  One possibility is

```
select a.a, b.b, c.c
from a full join
     b
     on a.? = b.? left join
     c
     on a.? = c.? or b.? = c.?;
```